# Inserir WHERE na consulta dando erro

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mariadb

Tenho essa consulta aqui que está puxando certo. Porém, agora quero colocar os que possuem o registro apenas dentro do mês vigente *(setembro, por exemplo)*. O meu `created_at` é `datetime`. Estou inserindo `WHERE "participantes_atividades.created_at" BETWEEN "2019-09-01" AND LAST_DAY("2019-09-01")`, mas tá dando erro. O meu código atual está assim:

```
'SELECT participantes.name, COUNT(participantes_atividades.atividade_id) AS qtd
        FROM participantes_atividades 
        JOIN participantes ON participantes.id = participantes_atividades.participante_id GROUP BY participantes_atividades.participante_id, participantes.name
        ORDER BY 2 DESC'
```

Estou trabalhando com o framework Laravel e estou recebendo o seguinte erro:

````
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'JOIN participantes ON participantes.id = participantes_atividades.participante_i' at line 4 (SQL: SELECT participantes.name, COUNT(participantes_atividades.atividade_id) AS qtd FROM participantes_atividades WHERE `participantes_atividades.created_at` BETWEEN "2019-08-01" AND "2019-08-30" JOIN participantes ON participantes.id = participantes_atividades.participante_id (GROUP BY participantes_atividades.participante_id), participantes.name ORDER BY 2 DESC)```
````

Comment: Retire estes parênteses que envolvem a cláusula GROUP BY. Note também que você está agrupando por participantes_atividades.participante_id mas este campo não consta da lista do SELECT.

Comment: Desculpa.. os parenteses foi teste meu.. Retirei e ainda está dando erro.

Comment: Mas continua colocando um campo na cláusula GROUP BY que não consta da lista de campos do SELECT. Também não entendi por qual razão a mensagem de erro apresenta um comando SQL diferente do que você colocou na pergunta.

Comment: Eu estou precisando agrupar a quantidade de atividades que um participante tem para poder fazer um ranking. Por isso o `Group by`.

Comment: Mas você está agrupando por participantes_atividades.participante_id e este campo não está em seu SELECT. Se não deseja o campo participantes_atividades.participante_id então agrupe apenas por participantes.name.

Comment: Tá sim.. no count... 

Na verdade eu não preciso do ID. Preciso apenas a quantidade de atividades e o nome do participante... é o que está trazendo atualmente. Mas agora, eu só preciso saber desses resultado, apenas os que foram criados no mês atual.

Comment: Se está na função de agregação então não deve constar da cláusula GROUP BY.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Amigo, no select que esta apresentado no seu erro, além de faltar o campo `participante_id` você esta colocando a condição `where` na ordem errada, tente assim:

```
SELECT participantes.name, participantes_atividades.participante_id, COUNT(participantes_atividades.atividade_id) AS qtd 
        FROM participantes_atividades 
        JOIN participantes ON participantes.id = participantes_atividades.participante_id
        WHERE participantes_atividades.created_at BETWEEN "2019-08-01" AND "2019-08-30"
        GROUP BY participantes_atividades.participante_id, participantes.name ORDER BY 2 DESC
```

Comment: Obrigado Murilo! 

Sua resposta está quase certa.. só precisei alterar o `ORDER BY` para 3. Mas funcionou certinho.

Obrigado mesmo assim.

Answer (score 1):

Você deve adicionar na clausula select o campo "participantes_atividades.participante_id" para poder agrupar por ele.

```
SELECT participantes.name, participantes_atividades.participante_id, COUNT(participantes_atividades.atividade_id) AS qtd
    FROM participantes_atividades 
    JOIN participantes
        ON participantes.id = participantes_atividades.participante_id
    GROUP BY participantes_atividades.participante_id, participantes.name
    ORDER BY 2 DESC;
```

Comment: Oi Leonardo, desculpa.. não entendi.. 
Eu estou tentando pegar apenas os resultados do mês vigente. esse código traz todos como já está.

Comment: só mandei um exemplo, a alteração em relação ao seu código foi só a primeira linha. Faz o seguinte: adiciona ", participantes_atividades.participante_id" na linha select e seja feliz.